# How to Make Tags Persist When Updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

The tags persist during:

```
  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
      respond_modal_with @goal, location: root_path
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end
```

but when I update the goal via:

```
  def mark_accomplished
    @goal.update(accomplished: true)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
      end
  end
```

The tags for that goal then disappears when a user clicks on the `mark_accomplished` button:

```
<%= link_to 'Accomplished', mark_accomplished_path(goal), remote: true, method: 'put',  %>
```

The route:

```
get '/goal_signup/', to: 'goals#goal_signup', as: 'goal_signup'
```

It has something to do with the tags [(`gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'`)](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) because this problem occurs in similar situations with my habits MVC. I'm using goals as the main example here, but let me know if you want the habits too to provide more context.

**goal.rb**

```
 class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :publish, ->{ where(:conceal => false) }
    belongs_to :user
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :accomplished, -> { where(accomplished: true) }
    scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: nil) }
    before_save :set_tag_owner

    def set_tag_owner
      # Set the owner of some tags based on the current tag_list
      set_owner_tag_list_on(self.user, :tags, self.tag_list)
      # Clear the list so we don't get duplicate taggings
      self.tag_list = nil
    end
end
```

**TagsController**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used(20)
    # The tags for all users and habits.
    @special_tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.includes(:taggings)
                                         .where('taggings.taggable_type' => ['Habit','User','Valuation','Goal'])
                                         .most_used(10)
    # to get tags where the current user is the tagger
    @user_tags = current_user.owned_tags
  end

  def show
    @tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**db**

```
  create_table "taggings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context", using: :btree

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evil is `before_save :set_tag_owner` , you have set `self.tag_list = nil`.
Therefore before saving Goal your tag list get emptied.

Its working in update action because you are setting tags again.

To solve this Issue, assign nil to tag_list only when you want to delete tags.

Comment: Writing callbacks which are dependent on other class, model is not a good practice. So you can assign `self.tag_list = nil ` in controller or you can write a service class for updating goals and write it there.

Comment: Probably you didn't called it on goal object , try @goal.tag_list = nil before update . Don't be sorry `to err is human` .

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I am not able to open your question. Probably you have solved it on your own and deleted question.